# Which module can hide or show text?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a site with puzzle and I need to hide or show some answer. It can be some photo or some text. It can't be block, I need a module that will be able to hide or show fields as is it done in the photo modules When I add some photo in any article. How can I hide or show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Quiz module, that looks awesome: https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz

> The Quiz module lets you create graded assessments in Drupal. A Quiz
> is given as a series of questions. Answers are then stored in the
> database. Scores and results are displayed during or after the quiz.

A simpler option might be the Peekaboo module: https://www.drupal.org/project/peekaboo

> Use cases: ... Fields that reveal more information
>
> Peekaboo can also be used purely for the Ajax functionality as a gimmick to reveal more information.